# curl with cookies, on MAC

Tags: curl, cookies

I visit a website. The home page is a disclaimer and I have to check the box to agree and proceed. Then I can access the search box. Now, these search box results can be a gold mine of thousands of URLs of content I want to download, but to click each one in Safari (MAC OS X) would take forever. If I use curl, it does not work because the cookie that got downloaded from the website is stored by Safari and the curl command does not send the cookie, so the server redirects to the home page to accept or reject the disclaimer. No username or password is required. Now, how can I get curl to transmit the cookies captured by Safari?